# How to pass correct id from data set (PHP)?

Tags: php

This is a part of index.php. This code is used to display the all the products in database.

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>     
      <form action="product.php?>" method="post">

           <tr class="info">
            <td align="center"><h3><?php echo $row['name'];?></h3></td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="success">
            <td align="center"><div class="grow pic"><img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['image'];?>"></div></td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="info">
            <td><?php echo substr($row['description'],0,75);?></td>
          </tr>

          <tr class="success">
            <td align="center"><input name="cart" type="submit" value="More Details"></td>
            </tr>

          <tr>
          <td></td>
          </tr>

      </form>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
```

There is a another page called product.php. When user click the "More details" button in index.php it will redirect to the product.php.

What I want to do is, I need to pass the correct product id for that page when user  click the "more details" button. How to do it?

Comment: Add a (hidden) form field that contains the value?

Comment: What's the point in the form? Just add a standard anchor and add a GET param of a product unique token, e.g. the ID, For example product.php?id=idhere

Comment: use a hidden field and pass your ID.

Comment: you can set form action with ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like the comments say, add a hidden input tag to your form:

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?=$row['id'];?>"/>
```

then in `product.php`, you can access it by:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

that's it..

Answer (score 1):

If using a submit button isn't an obligation, it would be better to use a simple anchor tag and drop the `form` tag :

```
 <tr class="success">
        <td align="center"><a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>">more details</a></td>
        </tr>
```

supposing your id fields is indeed called "id"... this is even better cause such request is supposed to be a `GET`, not a `POST`.

As a side remark please note the `align="center"` in your td is a bad practice, you should use CSS to style your page...

Answer (score 1):

`form` inside while doesnt make sense, you should omit `form`, 
you actually need to pass to `id` to `product.php`

so just add

`<tr><td><a href="product.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>">more details</a></td></tr>`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement is:
 - Use product id in form action method. For example:

```
<form action="product.php?productId=<?php echo $row['id'];?>>" method="post">
```

- Catch productId in the product.php. For exemple in native php:

> $productId = $_GET['productId'];